# Is there a way to send a message from a worker to other workers in node.js?

Tags: node.js, node-cluster

I can use `process.send` to send a message from a worker to a master. I can use the following code to send a message from the master to each worker.

```
for (var id in cluster.workers) {
  cluster.workers[id].send({command: 'doSomething'});
}
```

---

To send a message from a worker to other workers I have to send a message to the master and then have it forward the message. This results in the original sender also receiving the message and is something that I'd like to avoid but I can live with it!

I also tried sending the message directly from the worker like it's done in the master but `cluster.workers` is `undefined` in workers.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Try using a message system like something simple like Zero MQ (0MQ) or Kafka (more complex)

Comment: I suggest for you to use REDIS pub/sub, it will exactly give you what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compare `pid's` of the sender and the recipients:

```
worker.on('message', function(msg) {

  for (var id in cluster.workers) {

    if (cluster.workers[id].process.pid !== this.process.pid) {

      cluster.workers[id].send({
        command: 'doSomething',
        from: this.process.pid
      });

    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a simple package called [ipc-messenger](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ipc-messenger) that helps to do this. It provides an abstraction where details are hidden from the user.

The function `messageSiblings` can be used to send messages only to other workers and `messageWorkers` to send messages to all workers.

Example:

```
var ipcm = require('ipc-messenger')
ipcm.messageSiblings('hello')
```